# How to use Terminal command srm (or other) to secure delete a folder? Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: command-line, terminal

When I try to use `srm -m` to secure delete an empty folder in Trash, I get the following:

```
srm: /Users/tomhughes/.Trash/Recovered files is a directory
```

Comment: try `-rv` instead of `-m`

Comment: If it's empty, what's the need to secure delete? Why not just right click > Delete Immediately, or just empty the Trash?

Comment: Rastafarian, -rv worked.  Tetsujin, I'm learning a few basic Terminal command-lines.  Tom